# how to set xml contents value dynamically instead of hardcoding using java DOM parser

Tags: java, parsing, dom

I am trying to add the suffix for specific xml node attributes in copied xml. I am able to do so by using the `.setTextContent()` method. I don't want to give the hardcoded value in this method . I want to put it in dynamically at run time.please help...
Thanks,
Durai.

Comment: Can you add some sample code to your question showing what you've tried and why it isn't good enough?

Comment: I have the XML as follows: <Product id="ID_4" mappingType="Mapping_Type">
      <ID>7898</ID>
      <Name/>
      <Description/>
      <UniqueID External="41DFD3A XID="41DFD3A" locationOfControl="V6"/>  </Product>

Comment: In the above XML i want to add the suffix in the nodes <ID>7898, <UniqueID External="41DFD3A " for this changes i have used the  below code:  Node uniqueID2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("UniqueID").item(0);
       // update attributes
       NamedNodeMap attr2 = uniqueID2.getAttributes();
       Node nodeAttr2 = attr2.getNamedItem("External");
       nodeAttr2.setTextContent("222");

Comment: I want to try without hard coding the value "222" for the External attribute.

Comment: The value for External should be taken dynamically at run time, for this approach, Please provide the tips and help me to proceed in that manner. Similarly i need to change many Node attributes.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the value "222" coming from? if it's from another dynamic source (like user input or another xml file) then why not have it in a variable and call `nodeAttr2.setTextContent(somevariable)`?

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the user input . Thank you very much for your idea....